# UNC Path on os.system() not supported

Tags: python, cmd, unc

I am trying to run a program from an os.system() that takes a number of command line arguments call. Some of these arguments point to directories on a network that obviously have a UNC path.

Python interpreter is giving back the following:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there a way to allow UNC paths in the system method call? Or if not, is there an alternative library that can deal with this?

Comment: Use `os.splitdrive()` for UNC paths: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive. Another alternative to `os.system()` is `subprocess`, if that solves your purpose.

Comment: From my Wikipedia edit. You don't have to change to a directory to use it. UNC default paths are turned off by default as they used to crash older programs.[11] 

The Dword registry value DisableUNCCheck at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor[11] allows the default directory to be UNC. CD command will refuse to change but placing a UNC path in Default Directory in a shortcut to Cmd or by using the Start command. start "" /d \\127.0.0.1\C$ "cmd /k" (C$ share is for administrators).